# Is there a way to use `useProtocolCachePolicy` in watchOS?

Tags: swift, cache-control, watchos

I'm trying to use `URLRequest.CachePolicy.useProtocolCachePolicy` in my watch extension, but every request fails with 'can’t load from network' error.

I have seen the below answer:

[NSURLErrorDomain Code=-2000 "can’t load from network"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53197485/nsurlerrordomain-code-2000-can-t-load-from-network)

but what I want to do is use cached if valid or request policy. The best fit is to use `reloadRevalidatingCacheData` but it hasn't been implemented.

> @constant NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData Specifies that
>   the existing cache data may be used provided the origin source
>   confirms its validity, otherwise the URL is loaded from the
>   origin source. Unimplemented.

In iOS, the `useProtocolCachePolicy` works very similarly with `reloadRevalidatingCacheData`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/cachepolicy/useprotocolcachepolicy

But the requests fail in watchOS with `useProtocolCachePolicy` policy. It worked with `reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` by the way.

I'm not making HTTP or HTTPS byte-range request, so it seems like `useProtocolCachePolicy` work as iOS does, but it doesn't.

The only way seems to implement caching manually, but I want to know why it doesn't work and there is any out-of-box option for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Apple about this issue.

> Watch apps tend to be suspended very quickly so we recommend that developers use a background url session to ensure their api calls are still performed should an event such as backgrounding or suspension occur.

If anyone want to use .useProtocolCachePolicy policy, use background configuration.

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "xxx.xxx.xxxxx")
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
```